# pandas apply removing trailing zeros from a string in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fix a dataset where some string codes got mis-formatted as dates. The codes are strings (although some would parse as numbers) and importantly the code "4.1" is not the same as "4.10", so I've been careful to ensure the column's dtype is object. But I'm finding that `apply` is behaving very strangely:

```
import pandas as pd

code_mapping = {
  "04-Oct": "4.10"
}

def fix_code(c):
  return code_mapping.get(c,c)

data = pd.DataFrame(data={"code": ["04-Oct", "4.1a"], "value": [1.0, 2.0]})

print(data)
print(type(data.loc[0, "code"]))

data.code = data.code.apply(fix_code)

print(data)
print(type(data.loc[0, "code"]))
```

which produces this:

```
     code  value
0  04-Oct    1.0
1    4.1a    2.0
<class 'str'>
   code  value
0   4.1    1.0
1  4.1a    2.0
<class 'str'>
```

I'm converting a string ("04-Oct") to another string ("4.10") so I don't understand why pandas thinks it's ok to remove the trailing zero - it looks like internally its somehow casting to a float (if it can) and back again?

But things get even weirder: if I change the data so it *already* contains the value "4.1" in the column, but in a different row:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data={"code": ["04-Oct", "4.1"], "value": [1.0, 2.0]})
data.code = data.code.apply(fix_code)
print(data)
```

the conversion works as I would have expected:

```
   code  value
0  4.10    1.0
1   4.1    2.0
```

Can anybody explain this strange behaviour? I'm leaning towards bug but want to be sure there's not some arcane reason for this before I log it.

Comment: I get the expected output pandas 1.2.1, python 3.9.1, Manjaro

Comment: I was using pandas 1.2.0 & python 3.8.5, but updating to 1.2.1 does seem to fix it